# Openquery with TSQL: how to insert NULL in nvarchar column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, openquery

Im trying to use a stored procedure to insert some string values into a remote DB with Openquery. The argument `@val_a` can sometimes be some random string, but sometimes it can be `NULL`.

Following syntax works if `@val_a` is `NULL`, but not if it's a string `'asdf'`.

```
DECLARE @TSQL nvarchar(4000);
SELECT  @TSQL = 
    'UPDATE
        OPENQUERY(TEST,''SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE id = ' + convert(VARCHAR(MAX), @id) +''')
     SET
        val_a = ' + ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(MAX), @val_a), 'NULL') + ';'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

But, in order to work with the string `'asdf'`, the syntax has look like this:

```
DECLARE @TSQL nvarchar(4000);
SELECT  @TSQL = 
    'UPDATE
        OPENQUERY(TEST,''SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE id = ' + convert(VARCHAR(MAX), @id) +''')
     SET
        val_a = ''' + ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(MAX), @val_a), 'NULL') + ''';'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

But here, `NULL`s are inserted as the string `'NULL'`, not as a `NULL` value.

Is there a way to write the TSQL query in such form that both `NULL` and `'asdf'` are inserted correctly in the table?

Comment: What about `val_a = ' + ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(MAX), '''' + @val_a + ''''), 'NULL') + ';'`

Comment: ... oh God, yep, string concatenation. Thanks, I was almost pulling my hair out. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use like that:

```
val_a = ' + ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(MAX), '''' + @val_a + ''''), 'NULL') + ';'
```